# Creating grid of polygons with set area and minimum width within given extent using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid

I am trying to create a grid of features WITHIN an extent (such as a county boundary), preferably something four sided like a square, but doesn't necessarily need to be.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro at the moment.

The grid must be made of polygons with a certain area (36 sqkm) or close enough (within maybe 1 or 2 sqkm) but the sides of the polygons must be a minimum width so as to avoid long sliver polygons that technically meet the criteria of area but are too long on one side of the polygon. My previous testing such as with the fishnet tool, create grid index tool, and subdivide polygon tool are good at one or more of these things but are not perfect, it must meet the criteria above, especially within the boundary of a given extent. Creating a grid outside the extent of the AOI doesn't really work because clipping the grid to the extent of the county creates slivers along the edges of the extent.

The best way to visualize this is a machine that stamps out puzzle pieces for a weird shape like that of a county boundary. All the puzzle pieces have the same area, but they more or less look the same and fit together perfectly (without the interlocking nodules that make puzzles tricky to put together).

Comment: Suggest you edit your question and add some images to explain what it is you want, rather than talking about imaginary puzzle pieces.

Comment: I actually wrote code that produced a sparse grid of shapes that intersected with "keeper" geometries, and that section of the code was probably only 2-3 dozen lines, but it was optimized to work in a space with potentially over two billion such polygons (hence the subsetting). You have two choices: Roll your own or learn how to use Generate Fishnet and Select By Location to make what you want. Note that leaving the Answer open to both ArcGIS and QGIS will quickly get this Question closed for lacking *focus*, so choose an environment and make an attempt.

Comment: Would Dice https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dice.htm suit your needs?